# Example to understand git blame -M / -C

Tags: git, blame

I am working on understanding how `git blame -M` and `git blame -C` is working.

I created two files:

FileA:

```
A
B
C
```

FileB:

```
D
E
F
```

and added (and committed) them to my repository (hash `1234`). Then I copied the content of `FileB` to `FileA` so that it looks like this:

FileA:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

and committed the changes (hash `4567`).

Then I ran `git blame -C FileA`.

I expected the output:

```
1234 A
1234 B
1234 C
1234 D
1234 E
1234 F
```

but instead got:

```
1234 A
1234 B
1234 C
4567 D
4567 E
4567 F
```

Same when I move block `D E F` to `FileA` and do `git blame -M FileA`.

Did I misinterpret the purpose of `-C` and `-M` or did I miss something when constructing the test files?

**Update 1:**
Neither setting the  value of `-C` and `-M` to 3 helped, nor did handling larger text (tried it with 3 paragraphs of lorem ipsum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `git help blame`:

> ```
>    -C|<num>|
>        In addition to -M, detect lines moved or copied from other files that were modified in the same commit. This is
>        useful when you reorganize your program and move code around across files. When this option is given twice, the
>        command additionally looks for copies from other files in the commit that creates the file. When this option is given
>        three times, the command additionally looks for copies from other files in any commit.
>
>        <num> is optional but it is the lower bound on the number of alphanumeric characters that git must detect as
>        moving/copying between files for it to associate those lines with the parent commit. **And the default value is 40**. If
>        there are more than one -C options given, the <num> argument of the last -C will take effect.
> ```

Notice the **And the default value is 40**? Your example only presents a change of 6 (or maybe 9) characters, which is well below the threshhold of 40...

I suspect your test input is not large enough for the algorithms to detect the text movement...

Edit: there's also the bit in there about "other files that were modified in the same commit". So here's an example:

```
$ git init /tmp/foo
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/foo/.git/
$ cd /tmp/foo
$ cp /etc/motd file1
$ cp /etc/magic file2
$ cp /etc/os-release file3
$ git add file1 file2 file3
$ git commit -m baseline
[master (root-commit) 36a1d7] baseline
 3 files changed, 19 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file1
 create mode 100644 file2
 create mode 100644 file3
$ head -5 file2 >> file1
$ head -5 file3 >> file1
$ sed -i 1,5d file3
$ git add file1 file3
$ git commit -m second
[master b7a683] second
 2 files changed, 8 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
$ git log --pretty=oneline
 b7a683 (HEAD, master) second
 36a1d7 baseline
$ git blame file1
 ^36a1d7 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  1) 
 ^36a1d7 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  2) The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
 ^36a1d7 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  3) the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
 ^36a1d7 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  4) individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
 ^36a1d7 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  5) 
 ^36a1d7 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  6) Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
 ^36a1d7 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  7) permitted by applicable law.
 b7a6839 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:21:41 -0500  8) # Magic local data for file(1) command.
 b7a6839 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:21:41 -0500  9) # Insert here your local magic data. Format is described in magic(5).
 b7a6839 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:21:41 -0500 10) 
 b7a6839 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:21:41 -0500 11) PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
 b7a6839 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:21:41 -0500 12) NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
 b7a6839 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:21:41 -0500 13) VERSION_ID="7"
 b7a6839 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:21:41 -0500 14) VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
 b7a6839 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:21:41 -0500 15) ID=debian
$ git blame -C file1
 ^36a1d7 file1 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  1) 
 ^36a1d7 file1 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  2) The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
 ^36a1d7 file1 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  3) the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
 ^36a1d7 file1 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  4) individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
 ^36a1d7 file1 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  5) 
 ^36a1d7 file1 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  6) Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
 ^36a1d7 file1 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500  7) permitted by applicable law.
 b7a6839 file1 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:21:41 -0500  8) # Magic local data for file(1) command.
 b7a6839 file1 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:21:41 -0500  9) # Insert here your local magic data. Format is described in magic(5).
 b7a6839 file1 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:21:41 -0500 10) 
 ^36a1d7 file3 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500 11) PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
 ^36a1d7 file3 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500 12) NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
 ^36a1d7 file3 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500 13) VERSION_ID="7"
 ^36a1d7 file3 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500 14) VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
 ^36a1d7 file3 (Joe User 2015-03-26 17:19:10 -0500 15) ID=debian
```

Note that, without `-C`, `git blame` just attributes the new lines to the second commit. But with it, it attributes the last 5 lines to `file3` from the first commit, because 1) that's where they came from, 2) the segment is large enough, and 3) `file3` was also modified in the second commit. The lines from `file2` are not recognized, because, while the segment is large enough, `file2` was not modified in the second commit.

Also, note the difference between `-M`, which detects content movement within a file, and `-C` which detects movement/copying between different files.

Comment: I read that too but I got confused by the term "character" since I assumed that it would track blocks linewise. Trying it with larger text did not work either (generated 3 paragraphs of lorem ipsum text and copied a block from one file to another) nu matter what value for <num> I chose

Comment: OK. I could reconstruct your example for `git blame -C` . But you I was not able to reconstruct detected movement between files

Comment: Also the documentation says: `When this option is given three times, the command additionally looks for copies from other files in any commit.` . If I got that right, `git blame -CCC` should detect copies from files that have not necessarily been included in the same commit right? Did not work for me either